# Why is pointing out a plot hole in a question downvoted?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Just curious as to why questions that point out plot holes are downvoted so much?

Comment: Do you have a specific question (or questions) in mind? Because the usual applies, if a question doesn't show research, is poorly written beyond salvation etc etc it might get downvoted. It's hard to judge in the general case.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Don't be rude, and don't try to justify name-calling or personal attacks. Further rudeness will not be tolerated.

Comment: It is, because the same question can be asked in different ways: good (research done and shown, proper formatting etc) or bad (none of the above). If the former makes a point, I might upvote it, if the latter is just a rant I might DV it. It's really a case-by-case situation, hence my asking for you providing some questions samples as I fail to observe a trend in DVing plothole questions.

Comment: This seems excessively broad. Can you give any examples of this supposed phenomenon?

Comment: I will downvote "plot hole" questions if a) it's an excuse to post a users own fix-the-plot theory, b) it's a "I don't like this explanation so it's a plot hole" opinion post, or c) there's a very simple explanation that's being overlooked.  Basically all solid reasons to downvote any question, regardless of plot-holes or not.

Comment: @Radhil, A very closed minded opinion. A huge plot hole here, but yet up-voted. https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8961/if-obi-wan-and-yoda-were-trying-to-keep-luke-safe-from-vader-why-would-they-let But, by and large plot hole questions are down voted, just for being a plot hole question

Comment: @KyloRen - *shrug*  OK, that's nice?  Star Wars and Harry Potter are full of holes, and are pretty popular.  If that's the sum result of other people's votes, so be it.  I don't require other people to agree with me, and oddly enough, that tends to make me more open minded than you seem to think.

Comment: @Radhil, And just to be clear, most people don't specifically state that it is a plot hole, only in the comments does this usually become apparent and from there all goes down hill (most times).

Comment: @KyloRen alright, you provided a "plothole question" with zero DVs (so they _do_ exist), but no example of a (heavily) DVed one. For instance, out of 132 questions including ["plot hole"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22plot+hole%22++is%3Aq) or ["plothole"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22plothole%22++is%3Aq+), [only 15 of them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22plot+hole%22++is%3Aq+score%3A..0) (so roughly 10%) have a score <=0. Granted that only accounts for score and not exactly DVs, but I still don't see the DV trend. Then, could you give some examples?

Comment: This question seems pretty clear.

Answer (score 15):

Because pointing out plotholes is boring, and most of us that have been here a while are beyond sick of seeing them, for the following reasons:

1. Most of them are not plot holes. A "plot hole" is a very specific term for a place where there is a direct contradiction between two parts of the script that happened on-screen. Just because something isn't explained, or seems unreasonable, or unlikely, etc., doesn't make it a plot hole. It just means you have to use your imagination to fill in the gaps. Which is the whole point of fiction.
2. Most of them have no "official" answer. They're just things the writers didn't think were remotely important enough to bother putting in the script.
3. Many of them have very obvious "unofficial" answers, all of which are equally valid and none of which affect the plot in any way.
4. And my personal pet peeve, historically *far too often*, the person asking the question is not genuinely looking for an answer, but rather just trying to show off how smart they are by pointing out what they think is a mistake in the movie. We have [MovieMistakes.com](https://www.moviemistakes.com/) for that nonsense. Most of us have noted the same mistakes in the movie already and just brushed them off as irrelevant, so we have no interest in seeing them brought up over and over, especially as they usually end up generating way more noise than light (since the OP will often refuse to accept any answer other than "you're so smart, you found a plot hole!".)

Comment: Ahh, I get it, People like you consider a plot hole as something that is not plausible. You don't want to accept it as something that could be possible and apparent.

Comment: "people like me"? And if its possible, its not a plot _hole_. See: https://imgur.com/gallery/L7zDu

Comment: A plot hole is very much real. Why is that uninteresting?

Comment: Asking if something is a plot hole *could* be an interesting question as it leaves an exercise to determine if there are any contradictions. Any "question" simply pointing out plot holes is not a question, and should be closed as such.

Comment: And they're uninteresting because in almost every case, *they're not plot holes*. Something not clearly explained to the audience is NOT the same as a plot hole.

Comment: Like this question, https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8961/if-obi-wan-and-yoda-were-trying-to-keep-luke-safe-from-vader-why-would-they-let

Comment: @KyloRen You thinking that they are interesting is a different issue from whether many people think they are uninteresting. You asked why they are downvoted. A big part of why is that many people find them tiresome and downvote them.